# [BigQuery]Cannot GROUP BY field references from SELECT list

Tags: join, group-by, google-bigquery

When running query statement with group by in Google **BigQuery**, it was failed, and show

```
Cannot GROUP BY field references from SELECT list alias xxx
```

I tried many times to obtain its rules, but failed either.
My investigation is below:

> a> Create tables and insert values
>
> Create table FFNR_A, FFNR_B CREATE TABLE FFNR_A (A1 INT NOT NULL,
> A2 INT NOT NULL, A3 INT NOT NULL);

> CREATE TABLE FFNR_B (B1 INT NOT
> NULL, B2 INT NOT NULL, B3 INT NOT NULL,B4 INT NOT NULL);
>
> INSERT INTO  FFNR_A VALUES (0, 3, 1); INSERT INTO  FFNR_A VALUES (1,
> 0, 2); INSERT INTO  FFNR_A VALUES (2, 1, 1); INSERT INTO  FFNR_A
> VALUES (3, 2, 2); INSERT INTO  FFNR_A VALUES (5, 3, 0); INSERT INTO
> FFNR_A VALUES (6, 3, 2); INSERT INTO  FFNR_A VALUES (7, 4, 1); INSERT
> INTO  FFNR_A VALUES (8, 4, 3);
>
> INSERT INTO  FFNR_B VALUES (1, 1, 2, 0); INSERT INTO  FFNR_B VALUES
> (2, 2, 3, 0); INSERT INTO  FFNR_B VALUES (3, 2, 4, 0); INSERT INTO
> FFNR_B VALUES (4, 1, 5, 0); INSERT INTO  FFNR_B VALUES (5, 7, 0, 0);
> INSERT INTO  FFNR_B VALUES (6, 8, 2, 0); INSERT INTO  FFNR_B VALUES
> (7, 7, 1, 0); INSERT INTO  FFNR_B VALUES (8, 8, 3, 0); INSERT INTO
> FFNR_B VALUES (0, 1, 3, 0);
>
> b> Run Query
>
> ```
> -- Cannot GROUP BY field references from SELECT list alias B1 at [3:60]
> SELECT   A0.`A1`, B1.`B1`,
>   FROM `xxx`.`FFNR_B` B1, `xxx`.`FFNR_A` A0
> WHERE (A0.`A2` = B1.`B1`) AND (A0.`A2` = B1.`B1`) GROUP BY B1.`B1`,
>  A0.`A1`  limit 2;
>
> -- Works
> SELECT   A0.`A1`, B1.`B2`,
>   FROM `xxx`.`FFNR_B` B1, `xxx`.`FFNR_A` A0
> WHERE (A0.`A2` = B1.`B1`) AND (A0.`A2` = B1.`B1`) GROUP BY B1.`B2`,
>  A0.`A1`  limit 2;
>
> -- Replace B1->A1 and column A1->A2
> -- If use B1(tab), failed either
>  SELECT   A0.`A2`, A1.`B1`,
>   FROM `xxx`.`FFNR_B` A1, `xxx`.`FFNR_A` A0
> WHERE (A0.`A1` = A1.`B1`) AND (A0.`A1` = A1.`B1`) GROUP BY A1.`B1`,
>  A0.`A2`  limit 2;
> ```

I didn't get any doc in BigQuery docs.
Can you give me any suggestions about the rules of group by?
Or
Is it a bug in BigQuery?

Thanks

Comment: GROUP BY is getting confused by B1 being table alias and column name in output. Just simply use table aliases different from column names to avoid it. Or simply use `GROUP BY B1, A1 ` or `GROUP BY 1, 2`

Comment: Thanks Mikhail; 
It seems that you are right--The table name/ailas-name can't be same with column name in "group by".
The issue can be hit in "group by" only,  It can't be hit in where/select-list caluses.

Comment: I try the statement below:
create table xxx.gb(gb int, db int);

"select gb from xxx.gb  
group by gb"

It is fine when running  query "select gb from xxx.gb", but failed when running with "group by".

So, it maybe a bug in BigQuer. Right?

Comment: just add alias to table `select gb from xxx.gb as t group by gb` - otherwise BigQuery think you are trying to Group by tables whole row which is not supported

Comment: Sure, I know the workaround of the issue, and will take the work-around too. It's just a note to others, it maybe a bug/limitation here in BigQuery. Thanks Mikhail

Comment: Don't see a bug, rather limitation - `struct` is not supported for `group by`. See more for [Groupable data types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#groupable_data_types) :o)

Comment: Yes, but the column  is defined to be "Int"/Integer, which can hit the issue too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concluding the discussion from the comments:

```
-- Cannot GROUP BY field references from SELECT list alias B1 at [3:60] 
SELECT A0.`A1`, B1.`B1`, FROM `xxx`.`FFNR_B` B1, `xxx`.`FFNR_A` A0 
WHERE (A0.`A2` = B1.`B1`) AND (A0.`A2` = B1.`B1`) GROUP BY B1.`B1`, A0.`A1` limit 2;
```

As @Mikhail Berlyant said, in your query, the GROUP BY is getting confused by B1 being table alias and column name in output. The table/alias name should not be the same with column name in GROUP BY. To avoid this issue, use table aliases different from column names or simply use GROUP BY B1, A1 or GROUP BY 1, 2. It is a limitation in BigQuery and not a Bug. Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#groupable_data_types) for more information about Groupable data types.

Comment: Thank, got it.But the column is defined to be int/integer, but not struct.i.e, "create table federationjdbc.jdbc.gb(gb int, db int);" as an simple reproduced case.        I tried the case of order by "  select A1 from federationjdbc.jdbc.A1  order by a1.A1;" which works fine; but failed in group by case "  select A1 from federationjdbc.jdbc.A1   group by a1.A1;". and the limitations of "order by" and "group by" in the link seems  same

Comment: @junhliu, I have updated my answer. If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.